# Set cookie before first render React.js

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js

I'm a beginner in ReactJs and I have an application that use cookie to set the application language on Server Side, but in my first render I don't have the cookie setup and then it's using the default language instead of the browser language. I'm currently setting the cookie on the `_app.tsx` with `useEffect`

is there a way to set this cookie before the first render?

I'm using `React 17v`, `NextJs 10v` and `next-translate`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you are using nextJs you can use the getStaticProps or getServerSideProps function afterwards, just pass the cookies as props to your component.
Anything just take a look here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching

Comment: While it's possible to do so with `getServerSideProps`, it won't work for `getStaticProps` as it runs at build-time and has no context of the request to access the cookies.